# Depth testing issues in OpenTK/OpenGL

Tags: opengl, opentk

I'm struggling to get my depth testing working correctly in an app.

Depth seems to be based entirely on draw order, as seen here: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YErS_loJW7w&feature=youtu.be

You can see in the video, the point cloud of Suzanne is in front of the Mesh model, but when rotated it ends up behind it.

I think the code below is everything relevant

```
// clear the render buffer....
GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
GL.DepthMask(true);
GL.ClearColor(Color.Black);
GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);          

// Render main 3d scene
GL.Enable(EnableCap.CullFace);
GL.CullFace(CullFaceMode.Back);
GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthClamp);
GL.DepthFunc(DepthFunction.Always);
GL.DepthMask(true);
```

I was under the impression that enabling Depth testing would make this work correctly.

What's going wrong?

Comment: Did you request some depth buffer bits when you created your GL context?  You may not get any unless you ask.

Comment: OpenGl is relatively new to me. How do I tell? Looking at the docs around the OpenTK GLControl that I am using it seems to indicate that a depthbuffer is provided. "...Notice that the GLControl provides a color- and a depth buffer, which we have to clear using GL.Clear()."

Answer (score 0):

Setting `GL.DepthFunc(DepthFunction.Always);` is making things go wrong. This is telling the GL to never discard fragments, even if they lie behind previously drawn objects. You should use the `GL_LESS` or `GL_LEQUAL` comparision mode.

Comment: Thanks foe your response. I have modified that to a LESS. And I assume fragments are getting discarded, but they still seem to discard based on draw order rather than z-order. Is this something I need to tell GL to do explicitly?